# Can a foreigner moving to Australia for more than 6 months immediately claim themselves as a tax resident?

Tags: taxes, australia

Assuming a foreigner is on a 6+ month contract starting from June (so they will spend more than 183 days in Australia in the tax year 2017), can they claim residency immediately after moving rather than receiving a refund at the end of the year?

The question is important because the tax rates are a lot higher for non-residents, so it will be nice to receive a salary with lower deductions from the very beginning.

Comment: I have no idea how Australian tax calculations work but as a general rule, the government charges income tax before hand and then if you are eligible for a refund, it provides you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 183-day rule is only one of a number of tests to determine Australian tax residency.  If you satisfy [any of the other tests of residency](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/International-tax-for-individuals/In-detail/Residency/), then you are considered a tax resident.

The ATO has a [helpful tool](https://www.ato.gov.au/Calculators-and-tools/Host/?anchor=AreYouAResident&anchor=AreYouAResident&anchor=AreYouAResident/questions#AreYouAResident/questions) to determine whether you are a tax resident.

It should be noted that the lower (resident) tax rate only [applies from the day you arrive in Australia with the intention of becoming an Australian tax resident](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Ind/Tax-free-threshold-for-newcomers-to-Australia/).